# How to get cakePHP i18n .pot files encoded in UTF-8?

Tags: cakephp, encoding, utf-8, internationalization, command-line-interface

I'm using the cake [i18n](http://api.cakephp.org/class/i18n-shell) command to extract the content of my `__()` functions in my application.
However, the default.pot output file is not encoded in UTF-8, and thus does not correctly display accentuated characters which is a problem since the main language is french (lot of 'é' , 'à' ...).

I'm using wamp server on Windows 7.

I've tried to change Windows console's encoding with chcp, to convert default.pot file in UTF-8 with notepad++ or PSpad editor, without success.

**Do you know any way to get this default.pot file in UTF-8 ?**

All the .php or .ctp files are edited with either Komodo or Geany, both on Windows and configured to use UTF-8.
Also i'm using subversion, if it helps.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: How have you determined that the file is not in UTF-8? A common mistake is to assume that a UTF-8 file must start with U+FEFF.

Comment: @MSalters well I assumed this because POedit couldn't open the file first. I opened the default.pot with Geany and saw that accentuated characters were replaced by strings like 'Ã¨'. As I said in the OP, I tried to convert it with notepad++ (which openened the file in ANSI) in UTF-8 but without success (accentuated characters could not be correctly displayed). I hope this helps.

Comment: The Notepad "Open..." dialog has an option to explicitly specify the encoding as UTF-8, which overrides the default. The fact that you did see `Ã¨` is in fact positive, as that's a clear sign of actual UTF-8 being incorrectly detected as Latin-1

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, I did manage to open it in UTF-8. But why does POedit tell me it 'Failed to convert in unicode' then ?

Comment: That's a different question, really. And reading theough the poedit website, I'm fairly sure it's a bug. It shouldn't be converting to Unicode; it's already Unicode.

Comment: Which version are you using, BTW? [Ticket 193](http://www.poedit.net/trac/ticket/193) suggests that you may run an outdated version.

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.6, which is the latest stable release according to the website. Is there a way to edit a file's "header" (i don't know if it's the right word for this) ? Maybe is it created as ANSI but then written in UTF-8. I've tried to open it with other editors : Geany opens it as ANSI (as notepad++), and with jEdit i get an error.

Comment: error I get with jEdit : "The file could not be loaded correctly (some data might be lost) with
the encoding "utf-8,Cp1252".
(See details in Activity Log)
Try selecting a different encoding.
It can be selected with the menu File->Reload with Encoding.
If you want it to be done automatically, add the candidates into
"List of fallback encodings" in Encodings pane of Global Options.
"

Comment: Sounds like the "common mistake" I referred to in earlier comments. Or your .pot file is compiled from a mixture of sources, some UTF-8, some not.

Comment: It could be that but I can't be sure since I don't know exactly how cake creates the .pot file. Thank you very much for your help anyway. I don't know how to give you credit for the answer since it's in comments though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to deal with this thanks to @Msalters. I changed the default encoding of my editor and overwrote wrong characters.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with cakephp 1.3 (not sure if it is fixed in 2.x): all "special" character which are not ANSI compliant (such as ä, ü, ö, ß), where extracted in the .pot file and there interpreted by ANSI (e.g.  "Ã¼" instead of "ü").

The solution mentioned by Camille (manually changing the characters) was not very feasable, since it was a lot of characters, this partly destroyed the .pot format and even worse an automated update of your .po file won't work.

The workaround I found was with the help of a comment in the php documentation for write() (which is used in the console task): http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#73764.

According to the description there, I extended the file /cake/console/libs/tasks/extract.php with two lines:

First line went into the function __buildFiles():

```
$string = utf8_decode($string);
```

I wrote it in line 351, but it just needs to be in the second foreach loop and of couse before the variable is used by the function.

the second line went into the function __writeHeader():

replace the line $File->write($output); with

```
$File->write(utf8_encode($output));
```

That did it for me, take care the updating your cakephp will overwrite this changes.